# Creating master detail pattern which hides detail view on mobile using responsive design frameworks

Tags: angularjs, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, reactjs

I'm looking to use master-detail pattern in which master master view holds a list of items and clicking on it loads all the info related to that item in detailed view. This works fine using both bootstrap or foundation. I can also hide the detail view for mobiles.

What I'd like to do is when clicking on an item in master view I want to change the view to detail view in mobile. I think it is possible with a bit of jquery to hide the master view and show the detail view on mobile. I'm not sure if it's the right approach, I'd like to know how people have tackled this problem. Any angularjs/react specific suggestions would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to have the `className` of your Master view determined by the state held in the enclosing component.  Something like;

```
<MasterView className={this.state.masterViewClass} />
```

(Obviously altered to fit your code, you likely would want to apply this to specific tags rather than the entire react element).

On clicking an element of the master view, change it's `masterViewClass` accordingly, leveraging bootstraps [Responsive Utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) to hide the elements you do not wish to show.